# Why doesn't a non-nullable string array get treated as a non-nullable reference type?

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

Given the following extension method:

```
public static void ResetToDefaults<T>(this IList<T?> source) {
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++) {
        source[i] = default;
    }
}
```

The following code, in the C# nullable context, only gives me a warning on one line:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
List<string?> stringListNull = new List<string?> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
string?[] stringArrayNull = new string?[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };

stringList.ResetToDefaults(); // Produces CS8620
stringListNull.ResetToDefaults();
stringArray.ResetToDefaults(); // No warning
stringArrayNull.ResetToDefaults();
```

Why do I not get CS8620 for `stringArray.ResetToDefaults()`?  I'm declaring it as an array of non-nullable `string`s, yet calling an extension method that expects a nullable type.

Comment: Maybe related to the fact that arrays are handled a bit specially wrt nullables? E.g. `var x = new string[3]; string y = x[0]` doesn't produce a warning